# Downloading zip files with python

Tags: python, python-requests

Using a simple code to download zip files

```
import requests 

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/1994/NOV/cm03NOV1994bhav.csv.zip'
save_path = 'D:/folder/Programming/Python/trading/Bhavcopy/bhavcopy.csv.zip'

download_url(url,save_path)
```

The end result is the creation of an invalid zip file. I tried to open the website by manually pasting the url on browser and got this

[image]

But when I open link via the original website i.e going the nse website and clicking button to download, the link works.

Additional data

Here is the link from where you try downloading the file for yourself. https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm

I'm donwloading the files from first option(Bhavcopy) for the first date for which it is available (3rd Nov 1994)

Comment: That display isn't the result of an invalid zip file - it is saying that the session that you python script executes with doesn't have permission, but obviously your firefox session does have that permission.
My guess is that when you fill in the form it sets something in the session - or it looks at the page the link comes from -

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the invalid zip file is not actually the result of a bad download but rather just something that python created to write the data to. On a second note, how would I go about giving python the credentials, the website is available for everyone to use, there is no login mechanism in place that would prevent a download

Comment: That isn't anything that Python produces - you get the same result in firefox when you go direct to that zip file. It is the web server telling you that you can't download the file.
It could be that the server looks at the referer page (ie it wont let you download without going through the form.

Comment: if you ant bhavcopy previous to 2016 use Selenium. This method works for bhavcopy after 2016 Jan only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send referer headers:

```
headers = {'Referer':'https://www1.nseindia.com'}
```

...

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True,headers=headers)
```

Comment: can you please explain what headers does here ? And how would one come up with correct headers ?